# Why is there an ID present at the end of the OTP SMS which comes for Firebase Phone Number Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Can anyone help me with something I don't understand, I have been searching for a long time with no results.

In the SMS that comes with OTP for firebase phone number auth, there is an ID which is appended to the expected message.

The expected message format is:

`%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.` (as it is shown in authentication / templates in firebase console).

Expected Result:

> 123456 is your verification code for app-name.

But the message comes as follows:

> 123456 is your verification code for app-name.
>
> A1bcdE2FG3h

I'm not sure what **A1bcdE2FG3h** (altered but in same format) this ID is, or where it comes from.  Does anyone have any idea about this, and how to remove it from the OTP message? Thanks in advance!

I have enabled SafetyNet for this app (Not sure if relevant with this particular issue).

More details about app:

```
"react-native": "0.64.0",

"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.2.0"

"Testing environment": "android"
```